# Python не открывается файл: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите разобраться...

Перерыл все интернеты, не могу понять, почему этот скрипт:

```
s = "C:\\PP\\Hello.py"
print(s)
exec(open(s).read())
```

выдает такую ошибку:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-f408a41958d0> in <module>
      5 s = "C:\\PP\\Hello.py"
      6 print(s)
----> 7 exec(open(s).read())

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\PP\\Hello.py'
```

экспериментировал со слэшами, с отключением экранирования - ничего не помогает!

Система Windows Server 2016 Standart
Скрипт запускаю или из Jupiter Notebook, или делаю батник типа:

```
@echo off
python C:\1\Hello.py > output.log 2> errors.log
```

Ничего не помогает, одна и та же ошибка, что такого файла не существует.

Comment: C в пути английская или русская?

Comment: @insolor, в вопросе она английская. Автор, а у вас точно папка правильная? в батнике у вас другая папка

Comment: я ниже написал, что просто неверно сохранил файл, у меня вместо ".py" получился ".py.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Моя ошибка была в том, что я сохранил скрипт из блокнота, при сохранении заменил расширение на .py, но по факту файл получился с расширением .py.txt!
Пересохранил в файл из IDLE - все заработало.